# Логика создания кнопок на сайте для дальнейшего использования в БД

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, svg, frontend

есть интернет магазин , у которого предусмотрена возможность добавления товара в избранное , путем нажатия на кнопку лайк (svg сердечко), для реализации этого момента у меня есть svg картинка лайка до клика (просто не закрашенное сердечко) и есть svg кликнутого и оно уже залито цветом нужным , я очень хочу узнать как из следующего сделать работающую кнопку на сайт , при этом с возможностью дальнейшего использования его на Бэке, и если есть какая-нибудь инфа по тому как верстать подобные вещи на сайт, учитывая то, что потом это будет использоваться в реализации архитектуры сайта , буду очень признателен если поделитесь ссылкой) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.heart').click(function() {
  let id = this.dataset.elemid;
  let Y=0;
  if($(this).hasClass("active_heart")){
    Y=0;
  }else{
    Y=1;
  }
  /*$.ajax({//Используете это для передачи значения id лайкнутого товара и параметра убран или поставлен like
        type: "POST",
        url: 'xxx.php',
        data: "isLike": Y,"elementID":id
        success: function (response) {
            //Делаете тут что нибудь
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            console.log('ERROR'+exception);
        }
    });*/
  $(this).toggleClass('active_heart');
  $('#show').append('</br>idElem='+id+'</br>IsLike='+Y);
});
```

```css
.heart {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.heart svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.heart:hover .red,
.active_heart .red {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="heart" data-elemid="1111">
  <svg height="448pt" viewBox="0 0 448 448" width="448pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="red" d="m296 112c-27.675781-.09375-52.921875 15.800781-64.800781 40.800781l-7.199219 14.902344-7.199219-14.902344c-14.550781-30.269531-48.105469-46.445312-80.847656-38.976562s-55.964844 36.59375-55.953125 70.175781c0 82.089844 121.550781 149.878906 144 161.695312 22.441406-11.824218 144-79.695312 144-161.695312-.042969-39.746094-32.253906-71.957031-72-72zm0 0"/>
    <path d="m224 0c-123.710938 0-224 100.289062-224 224s100.289062 224 224 224 224-100.289062 224-224c-.140625-123.652344-100.347656-223.859375-224-224zm3.527344 361.871094-3.527344 1.738281-3.527344-1.738281c-6.382812-3.136719-156.472656-78.039063-156.472656-177.871094.058594-48.578125 39.421875-87.941406 88-88 28.710938-.117188 55.636719 13.90625 72 37.496094 16.363281-23.589844 43.289062-37.613282 72-37.496094 48.578125.058594 87.941406 39.421875 88 88 0 99.832031-150.089844 174.734375-156.472656 177.871094zm0 0"/>
</svg>
</button>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Ориентировочный пример PHP кода для обработки события клика на Like( структуру вашей БД не знаю, так что могу лишь предполагать, что будет примерно так)

```
include_once 'NewConnect.php';//Подключаем Базу Данных
$like = $_POST['isLike'];
$elemID = $_POST['elementID'];
if($like==1){
    $sql01 = "INSERT INTO `Favorite products` (user_id,productID) VALUES (:user_id,:elem)";
    $req01 = $dbh->prepare($sql01);
    $req01->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req01->bindValue(':elem', $elemID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req01->execute();
}else{
    $sql01 = "DELETE IGNORE FROM `Favorite products` WHERE user_id = :user_id AND productID = :elem";
    $req01 = $dbh->prepare($sql01);
    $req01->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req01->bindValue(':elem', $elemID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req01->execute();
}
```

Надеюсь, поможет вам. Если есть вопросы - задавайте.